# Varying lineWidth in a CAShapeLayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I'm working on a little project where I want to draw a bezier curve. I want to be able to vary the `lineWidth` in different portions of the drawing.

Here's what I have:

```
CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pathLayer.frame = self.animationLayer.bounds;
pathLayer.bounds = pathRect;
pathLayer.geometryFlipped = YES;
pathLayer.path = path.CGPath;
pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
pathLayer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
```

How would I vary the width of the line? One solution might be to have multiple `UIBezierPath`s with multiple `CAShapeLayer`s, but it seems there should be a simpler, more elegant solution (something along the lines of specifying the `lineWidth` at the level where the `UIBezierPath` lines are specified).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIBezierPath` only has one `lineWidth` property, so it's not possible to draw varying line widths with one path. You would have to use multiple paths to achieve this effect.

Comment: Yup, I've "solved" this by adding multiple paths. No idea how many paths/layers I can realistically have in a view, though..

Comment: Depending on your needs (animation...), it might be better to draw the paths into a static image instead of creating layers for all the paths.